# Can these two rewrite rules be written in a better way/merged?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(stylesheets|javascript)/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(stylesheets|javascript)/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

it lets me do /foo/stylesheets/123456/bar.css which maps to /foo/stylesheets/bar.css and /stylesheets/123456/bar.css which maps to /stylesheets/bar.css

However I was just wondering if they could be merged somehow?

I tried changing it to just:

```
RewriteRule (stylesheets|javascript)/[0-9]+/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

but that didn't work for anything with /foo/stylesheets/

Thanksl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(stylesheets|javascript)/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1$2/$3 [L]
```

I'm just unsure how much performance it will give you (maybe even opposite).